# How Do I Display Different Messages Under Grand Total for Tax?

Tags: magento

I am wondering how I would go about adding a message under the grand total on the shopping cart, checkout and on customer emails that say either one of two messages if tax is enabled or not.

For example if someone in the UK or EU buys something, it will say under the grand total “Includes VAT at 20%”. If someone outside of the EU buy something, it will say under the grand total “UK Sales tax has been deducted”.

I have it already set up so the tax changes depending on which country you select, but I'm wondering how to display these messages now.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml

Adapt and add this code :

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress();
$country = $billingAddress->getCountryId();

if($country == "XX") {
echo "<p>Display this message if user is from XX.</p>";
}
```

Comment: Hi. I have tried adding this code to app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/totals.phtml, but I cannot make the if statement true. I have tried the codes "UK", "GB", "GBR", and "United Kingdom" and none of them work. (PS You forgot a semicolon at the end of the echo.)

Comment: Here is another way to get the customer's country : $country = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId();

Comment: Thank you this seemed to work on app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/totals.phtml. I have the messages I require showing under the total on the example.com/checkout/cart page, but on on the checkout page. I'm not sure where I would play this message on that page. I also would like to display the same on customer checkout emails. Thanks again!